# Order my df by hour minutes in ascending order from earliest to latest in r

Tags: r, sorting, time, rank

Does anyone know how I can order my df based on time to have the earliest times to the latest times, specifically for night time hours? After making the correct order, I then want to rank them. I've seen similar examples on here but for java. I broke up my time into hours, minutes, and seconds hoping it would make it easier. I thought I would arrange hours by descending order first then minutes and seconds in ascending order, and then use frank but Ive been having some trouble since hours 19-23 are actually earlier than hours 00-02.

My data frame looks like this:

```
Time        Hour    Minute      Second 
20:12:30    20      13          30
19:45:00    19      45          00
00:24:00    00      24          00
02:05:30    02      05          30
19:01:30    19      01          30
23:52:30    23      52          30
04:32:30    04      32          30
00:58:30    00      58          30
```

I would like to order the df so the earliest time, which is 19:01:30 in this df to be first, followed by 19:01:30 then 20:12:30 until 02:05:30, which is the latest time and therefore should be the last one  in the order. And then I would like to rank them in that order, so #1 is the earliest time.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why is 19:01:30 early than 00:24:00?  Also, ordering depends on the data types. So you need to show us the data type of each column.

Answer (score 0):

We could add one day to where the 'Hour' is less than 19 and `order` it

```
library(data.table)
library(lubridate)
setDT(df1)[order(fifelse(Hour < 19,
     as.POSIXct(Time, format = '%T') + days(1), as.POSIXct(Time, format = '%T')))]
```

-ouptut

```
        Time Hour Minute Second
1: 19:01:30   19      1     30
2: 19:45:00   19     45      0
3: 20:12:30   20     13     30
4: 23:52:30   23     52     30
5: 00:24:00    0     24      0
6: 00:58:30    0     58     30
7: 02:05:30    2      5     30
8: 04:32:30    4     32     30
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Time = c("20:12:30", "19:45:00", "00:24:00", "02:05:30", 
"19:01:30", "23:52:30", "04:32:30", "00:58:30"), Hour = c(20L, 
19L, 0L, 2L, 19L, 23L, 4L, 0L), Minute = c(13L, 45L, 24L, 5L, 
1L, 52L, 32L, 58L), Second = c(30L, 0L, 0L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 
30L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a vector with the correct order of hours that you want. You can then use `match` and arrange the dataframe.

```
library(dplyr)

correct_order <- c(19:23, 0:18)

df <- df %>% arrange(match(Hour, correct_order), Minute, Second)
df
#      Time Hour Minute Second
#1 19:01:30   19      1     30
#2 19:45:00   19     45      0
#3 20:12:30   20     13     30
#4 23:52:30   23     52     30
#5 00:24:00    0     24      0
#6 00:58:30    0     58     30
#7 02:05:30    2      5     30
#8 04:32:30    4     32     30
```

In base R, you can write this with `order` as -

```
df <- df[with(df, order(match(Hour, correct_order), Minute, Second)), ]
```